# Printing TensorFlow and NumPy values to stdout

Tags: python, windows, numpy, tensorflow, nan

I have some problem with printing numpy.float32() value to stdout.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

n_samples = 1000
batch_size = 100
num_steps = 20000

x_data = np.random.uniform(1, 10, (n_samples, 1))
y_data = 2 * x_data + 1 + np.random.normal(0, 2, (n_samples, 1))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1))

with tf.variable_scope('linear-regression'):
    k = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, 1)), name='slope')
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1,), name='bias')

y_pred = tf.matmul(x, k) + b
loss = tf.reduce_sum((y - y_pred) ** 2)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

display_step = 5000
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(num_steps):
        indices = np.random.choice(n_samples, batch_size)
        x_batch, y_batch = x_data[indices], y_data[indices]
        _, loss_val, k_val, b_val = session.run((optimizer, loss, k, b), feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch})
        if (i + 1) % display_step == 0:
            print(f'Epoch {i+1}: loss = {loss_val.item():.3f}, k = {np.sum(k_val).item():.3f}, b = {np.sum(b_val).item():.3f}')
```

When i'm trying to print values in last string I get something like this:

```
Epoch 5000: loss = nan, k = nan, b = nan
Epoch 10000: loss = nan, k = nan, b = nan
Epoch 15000: loss = nan, k = nan, b = nan
```

I'm using Visual Code (Windows 10). In debug mode i'm trying to print loss_val value and convert it to Python native float value and print after that, but getting None value.

Thanks for your help =)

P.S. TensorFlow 1.4.0, NumPy 1.14, Windows 10, Visual Code as IDE.

**Update**:

In debug mode stoppped in if-statment, I have tried

```
print(1)
```

and get:

```
None
1
```

What am i doing wrong? Looks like something redefine print().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing NaNs because the values in the network are exploding very quickly and become too large to fit in `float`. This explosion is caused primarily by your hyper-parameters:

- `k` initial value is too large, reduce the standard deviation, e.g.:

  ```py
  k = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, 1), stddev=0.001), name='slope')
  ```
- the learning rate is too high as well, try `0.01` instead of `0.05`;
- you should use `tf.reduce_mean` instead of `tf.reduce_sum` to keep the loss and the gradient adjusted to the batch size.

The result code:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, 1))

with tf.variable_scope('linear-regression'):
  k = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, 1), stddev=0.001), name='slope')
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1, ), name='bias')

y_pred = tf.matmul(x, k) + b
loss = tf.reduce_mean((y - y_pred) ** 2)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
```

PS. You should also consider normalizing the input if you want better results.

Comment: Thanks for your advices! It helps =)